# Sitecore JSS Can't resolve 'music/components/GenreList' in 'C:\Dev\sitecore_nine\samples\flo\musictore_react\src

Tags: jss

I Created a Component namend GenreList but i cannot add it to my ComponentFactory

Here is my gist: 
https://gist.github.com/Rian0702/10c3e7068b8e15617bb034dcfffca495

And a picture of my App structure... i really hope i am missing to a slash or such simple thing. 
Let me know if you need anything else. 
Thanks for helping in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I would try changing is the `import` statement in `GenreList.js` to the following - note the absence of curly brackets `{}` and the adjusted path based on the folder structure:

`import GenreList from 'music/components/GenreList/GenreList';`

Currently, the statement is:

`import { GenreList } from 'music/components/GenreList';`

but the `GenreList` component is actually one level deeper in the path and the code uses a `default` export and not a named export, i.e. `export default` vs. `export const GenreList`.

Comment: thank you. I ended up using a index.js inside music/components. and imported genreList as:
`import GenreList from './GenreList/GenreList';`